# why dlmalloc allocated chunk header contains 4 bytes of previous allocated chunk

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory-management

I was going through dynamic memory allocator called doug lea memory allocator which uses best fit method to allocate memory on heap. The algorithm is a basis for more other algorithms but I found that in case of an allocated chunk the header of that chunk contains last 4 bytes of data of the previous chunk. I checked the algorithm explanation but couldn't find the reason. I want to know what is the purpose of this allocation of 4 bytes of previous chunk?
    I also came up with an explanation of this as the allocation of .dtors section in other chunk for synchronisation and proper use of space but want to know the details.

[this is the figure of chunks of dlmalloc algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc3mN.jpg)

The above figure contains the structures of allocated chunk and free chunk. In free chunk the first 4 bytes contains the size of the previous chunk, but in allocated chunk the first four bytes contains **the last four bytes of user data of the previous allocated chunk** which seems a little confusing to me and I want to know what is the purpose of allocating just the four bytes of previous allocated chunk in the current chunk.

Comment: Can you post more details, specifically the memory addresses of the allocated chunk, the address of the header (presumably a few bytes behind the allocated chunk) and maybe a hex dump of the header? I would initially suspect an alignment problem rather than dlmalloc being broken.

Comment: (In allocating space for (arrays of) `struct`s, be sure to let the `sizeof` operator determine the size necessary instead of second guessing it (e.g., sum sizes of components "by hand").)

Answer (score 2):

Yes chunks do overlap. Once upon a time memory was very expensive.
This is a feature in dlmalloc, ptmalloc, and glibc malloc.

There is a pretty decent explanation in the code:

```
This struct declaration is misleading (but accurate and necessary).
It declares a "view" into memory allowing access to necessary
fields at known offsets from a given base. See explanation below.

struct malloc_chunk {

 INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
 INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

 struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
 struct malloc_chunk* bk;
};
```

malloc_chunk details:

```
(The following includes lightly edited explanations by Colin Plumb.)

Chunks of memory are maintained using a `boundary tag' method as
described in e.g., Knuth or Standish.  (See the paper by Paul
Wilson ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/allocsrv.ps for a
survey of such techniques.)  Sizes of free chunks are stored both
in the front of each chunk and at the end.  This makes
consolidating fragmented chunks into bigger chunks very fast.  The
size fields also hold bits representing whether chunks are free or
in use.

An allocated chunk looks like this:


 chunk->+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Size of previous chunk, if allocated            | |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Size of chunk, in bytes                         |P|
  mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             User data starts here...                          .
        .                                                               .
        .             (malloc_usable_space() bytes)                     .
        .                                                               |
next  ->+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Size of chunk                                     |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+


Where "chunk" is the front of the chunk for the purpose of most of
the malloc code, but "mem" is the pointer that is returned to the
user.  "Nextchunk" is the beginning of the next contiguous chunk.

Chunks always begin on even word boundries, so the mem portion
(which is returned to the user) is also on an even word boundary, and
thus at least double-word aligned.

Free chunks are stored in circular doubly-linked lists, and look like this:

chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Size of previous chunk                            |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
`head:' |             Size of chunk, in bytes                         |P|
  mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Forward pointer to next chunk in list             |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Back pointer to previous chunk in list            |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        |             Unused space (may be 0 bytes long)                .
        .                                                               .
        .                                                               |
 next-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
`foot:' |             Size of chunk, in bytes                           |
        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

The P (PREV_INUSE) bit, stored in the unused low-order bit of the
chunk size (which is always a multiple of two words), is an in-use
bit for the *previous* chunk.  If that bit is *clear*, then the
word before the current chunk size contains the previous chunk
size, and can be used to find the front of the previous chunk.
The very first chunk allocated always has this bit set,
preventing access to non-existent (or non-owned) memory. If
prev_inuse is set for any given chunk, then you CANNOT determine
the size of the previous chunk, and might even get a memory
addressing fault when trying to do so.

Note that the `foot' of the current chunk is actually represented
as the prev_size of the NEXT chunk. This makes it easier to
deal with alignments etc but can be very confusing when trying
to extend or adapt this code.

The two exceptions to all this are

 1. The special chunk `top' doesn't bother using the
    trailing size field since there is no next contiguous chunk
    that would have to index off it. After initialization, `top'
    is forced to always exist.  If it would become less than
    MINSIZE bytes long, it is replenished.

 2. Chunks allocated via mmap, which have the second-lowest-order
    bit (IS_MMAPPED) set in their size fields.  Because they are
    allocated one-by-one, each must contain its own trailing size field.
```

Comment: No, chunks *don't* overlap, and this is nothing to do with saving memory. The malloc_chunk structure points at the last word of the previous chunk, pure and simple, and that's done because it's the easiest way to represent the boundary tag structure in C.

Answer (score 0):

I have not studied `dlmalloc` specifically, but here is a possible explanation:

On an architecture with objects that require 16 byte alignment (as does Intel SSE), the address returned must be multiple of 16.  If the header has 12 bytes of information, containing the size of the chunk, and some linkage information to coalesce the chunk with the previous one, the header might be defined as having a length of 16, the first four bytes being used for the end of the previous allocated chunk. If this previous chunk is free, this space could be used by the allocator for optimizations.